# How to substract current utc time from php iso utc?

Tags: javascript, date, angular, typescript

I want to get current time in `UTC`, substract it from `ISO UTC string` which I'm getting from backend in the following format: `2016-11-29T17:53:29+0000` (*ISO 8601 date, i guess?*) and get an answer in milliseconds.

What is the shortest way to do it in javascript? I'm using angular 2 and typescript frontend.

Comment: I would Google `javascript convert iso 8601` and look through the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current time using:

`var now = Date.now()`

And convert the string to a milliseconds timestamp using:

`var ts = (new Date('2016-11-29T17:53:29+0000')).getTime()`

And then subtract the values:

`var diff = ts - now`